# Setting text color, outline, and padding on Material-ui Autocomplete component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We'd like to change the text color, outline, and padding on a Material-ui Autocomplete component.

The code looks like this:

```
              <FormControlLabel
                label="Please enter desired service:"
                labelPlacement="start"
                control={
                  <Autocomplete
                    id="services"
                    options={props.serviceTypes}
                    getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
                    className={classes.inputRoot}
                    style={{ width: 400, paddingLeft: 20 }}
                    renderInput={params => (
                      <TextField
                        {...params}
                        label=""
                        className={classes.inputRoot}
                        variant="outlined"
                        fullWidth
                      />
                    )}
                    onChange={setService}
                  />
                }
              />
```

We are able to change the TextInput color via code like this

```
                        InputProps={{
                          className: classes.inputColor
                        }}
```

but applying a style this way impacts the AutoComplete functionality (it loses the autocomplete functionality and behaves like a normal TextField).

We've tried a number of style and className options to no avail.

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: I'd recommend reproducing the issue with a codesandbox or similar example and editing your post with the link.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here is the approach you tried (which worked as far as styling, but broke the Autocomplete functionality):

```
renderInput={params => (
    <TextField
       {...params}
       label=""
       InputProps={{
          className: classes.inputColor
       }}
       variant="outlined"
       fullWidth
    />
)}
```

The above approach causes problems because the `Autocomplete` component [passes InputProps](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.6.1/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js#L297) as part of the `params` passed to `TextField` so the `InputProps` passed explicitly will completely replace the `InputProps` in `params`.

Instead, you should leverage the `inputRoot` [CSS class for the Autocomplete component](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#css):

```
<Autocomplete classes={{inputRoot: classes.inputRoot}} .../>
```

Below is a working v4 example (v5 example further down) that customizes the text color, outline colors, and padding-left of the input and label.

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& .MuiInputLabel-outlined:not(.MuiInputLabel-shrink)": {
      // Default transform is "translate(14px, 20px) scale(1)""
      // This lines up the label with the initial cursor position in the input
      // after changing its padding-left.
      transform: "translate(34px, 20px) scale(1);"
    },
    "&.Mui-focused .MuiInputLabel-outlined": {
      color: "purple"
    }
  },
  inputRoot: {
    color: "purple",
    // This matches the specificity of the default styles at https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.3/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js#L90
    '&[class*="MuiOutlinedInput-root"] .MuiAutocomplete-input:first-child': {
      // Default left padding is 6px
      paddingLeft: 26
    },
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "green"
    },
    "&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "red"
    },
    "&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "purple"
    }
  }
}));

export default function ComboBox() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      classes={classes}
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 400 }}
      renderInput={(params) => {
        return (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Combo box"
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King", year: 2003 },
  { title: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year: 1966 },
  { title: "Fight Club", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back", year: 1980 },
  { title: "Forrest Gump", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Inception", year: 2010 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers", year: 2002 },
  { title: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", year: 1975 },
  { title: "Goodfellas", year: 1990 },
  { title: "The Matrix", year: 1999 },
  { title: "Seven Samurai", year: 1954 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope", year: 1977 },
  { title: "City of God", year: 2002 },
  { title: "Se7en", year: 1995 },
  { title: "The Silence of the Lambs", year: 1991 },
  { title: "It's a Wonderful Life", year: 1946 },
  { title: "Life Is Beautiful", year: 1997 },
  { title: "The Usual Suspects", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Léon: The Professional", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Spirited Away", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Saving Private Ryan", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in the West", year: 1968 },
  { title: "American History X", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Interstellar", year: 2014 },
  { title: "Casablanca", year: 1942 },
  { title: "City Lights", year: 1931 },
  { title: "Psycho", year: 1960 },
  { title: "The Green Mile", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Intouchables", year: 2011 },
  { title: "Modern Times", year: 1936 },
  { title: "Raiders of the Lost Ark", year: 1981 },
  { title: "Rear Window", year: 1954 },
  { title: "The Pianist", year: 2002 },
  { title: "The Departed", year: 2006 },
  { title: "Terminator 2: Judgment Day", year: 1991 },
  { title: "Back to the Future", year: 1985 },
  { title: "Whiplash", year: 2014 },
  { title: "Gladiator", year: 2000 },
  { title: "Memento", year: 2000 },
  { title: "The Prestige", year: 2006 },
  { title: "The Lion King", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Apocalypse Now", year: 1979 },
  { title: "Alien", year: 1979 },
  { title: "Sunset Boulevard", year: 1950 },
  {
    title:
      "Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb",
    year: 1964
  },
  { title: "The Great Dictator", year: 1940 },
  { title: "Cinema Paradiso", year: 1988 },
  { title: "The Lives of Others", year: 2006 },
  { title: "Grave of the Fireflies", year: 1988 },
  { title: "Paths of Glory", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Django Unchained", year: 2012 },
  { title: "The Shining", year: 1980 },
  { title: "WALL·E", year: 2008 },
  { title: "American Beauty", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight Rises", year: 2012 },
  { title: "Princess Mononoke", year: 1997 },
  { title: "Aliens", year: 1986 },
  { title: "Oldboy", year: 2003 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in America", year: 1984 },
  { title: "Witness for the Prosecution", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Das Boot", year: 1981 },
  { title: "Citizen Kane", year: 1941 },
  { title: "North by Northwest", year: 1959 },
  { title: "Vertigo", year: 1958 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi", year: 1983 },
  { title: "Reservoir Dogs", year: 1992 },
  { title: "Braveheart", year: 1995 },
  { title: "M", year: 1931 },
  { title: "Requiem for a Dream", year: 2000 },
  { title: "Amélie", year: 2001 },
  { title: "A Clockwork Orange", year: 1971 },
  { title: "Like Stars on Earth", year: 2007 },
  { title: "Taxi Driver", year: 1976 },
  { title: "Lawrence of Arabia", year: 1962 },
  { title: "Double Indemnity", year: 1944 },
  { title: "Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind", year: 2004 },
  { title: "Amadeus", year: 1984 },
  { title: "To Kill a Mockingbird", year: 1962 },
  { title: "Toy Story 3", year: 2010 },
  { title: "Logan", year: 2017 },
  { title: "Full Metal Jacket", year: 1987 },
  { title: "Dangal", year: 2016 },
  { title: "The Sting", year: 1973 },
  { title: "2001: A Space Odyssey", year: 1968 },
  { title: "Singin' in the Rain", year: 1952 },
  { title: "Toy Story", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Bicycle Thieves", year: 1948 },
  { title: "The Kid", year: 1921 },
  { title: "Inglourious Basterds", year: 2009 },
  { title: "Snatch", year: 2000 },
  { title: "3 Idiots", year: 2009 },
  { title: "Monty Python and the Holy Grail", year: 1975 }
];
```

[image: Edit customized Autocomplete (forked)]

Here is an equivalent example for v5 using `styled`:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const StyledAutocomplete = styled(Autocomplete)({
  "& .MuiInputLabel-outlined:not(.MuiInputLabel-shrink)": {
    // Default transform is "translate(14px, 20px) scale(1)""
    // This lines up the label with the initial cursor position in the input
    // after changing its padding-left.
    transform: "translate(34px, 20px) scale(1);"
  },
  "&.Mui-focused .MuiInputLabel-outlined": {
    color: "purple"
  },
  "& .MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot": {
    color: "purple",
    // This matches the specificity of the default styles at https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.3/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js#L90
    '&[class*="MuiOutlinedInput-root"] .MuiAutocomplete-input:first-of-type': {
      // Default left padding is 6px
      paddingLeft: 26
    },
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "green"
    },
    "&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "red"
    },
    "&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "purple"
    }
  }
});

export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <StyledAutocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 400 }}
      renderInput={(params) => {
        return (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Combo box"
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King", year: 2003 },
  { title: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year: 1966 },
  { title: "Fight Club", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back", year: 1980 },
  { title: "Forrest Gump", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Inception", year: 2010 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers", year: 2002 },
  { title: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", year: 1975 },
  { title: "Goodfellas", year: 1990 },
  { title: "The Matrix", year: 1999 },
  { title: "Seven Samurai", year: 1954 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope", year: 1977 },
  { title: "City of God", year: 2002 },
  { title: "Se7en", year: 1995 },
  { title: "The Silence of the Lambs", year: 1991 },
  { title: "It's a Wonderful Life", year: 1946 },
  { title: "Life Is Beautiful", year: 1997 },
  { title: "The Usual Suspects", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Léon: The Professional", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Spirited Away", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Saving Private Ryan", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in the West", year: 1968 },
  { title: "American History X", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Interstellar", year: 2014 },
  { title: "Casablanca", year: 1942 },
  { title: "City Lights", year: 1931 },
  { title: "Psycho", year: 1960 },
  { title: "The Green Mile", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Intouchables", year: 2011 },
  { title: "Modern Times", year: 1936 },
  { title: "Raiders of the Lost Ark", year: 1981 },
  { title: "Rear Window", year: 1954 },
  { title: "The Pianist", year: 2002 },
  { title: "The Departed", year: 2006 },
  { title: "Terminator 2: Judgment Day", year: 1991 },
  { title: "Back to the Future", year: 1985 },
  { title: "Whiplash", year: 2014 },
  { title: "Gladiator", year: 2000 },
  { title: "Memento", year: 2000 },
  { title: "The Prestige", year: 2006 },
  { title: "The Lion King", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Apocalypse Now", year: 1979 },
  { title: "Alien", year: 1979 },
  { title: "Sunset Boulevard", year: 1950 },
  {
    title:
      "Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb",
    year: 1964
  },
  { title: "The Great Dictator", year: 1940 },
  { title: "Cinema Paradiso", year: 1988 },
  { title: "The Lives of Others", year: 2006 },
  { title: "Grave of the Fireflies", year: 1988 },
  { title: "Paths of Glory", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Django Unchained", year: 2012 },
  { title: "The Shining", year: 1980 },
  { title: "WALL·E", year: 2008 },
  { title: "American Beauty", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight Rises", year: 2012 },
  { title: "Princess Mononoke", year: 1997 },
  { title: "Aliens", year: 1986 },
  { title: "Oldboy", year: 2003 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in America", year: 1984 },
  { title: "Witness for the Prosecution", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Das Boot", year: 1981 },
  { title: "Citizen Kane", year: 1941 },
  { title: "North by Northwest", year: 1959 },
  { title: "Vertigo", year: 1958 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi", year: 1983 },
  { title: "Reservoir Dogs", year: 1992 },
  { title: "Braveheart", year: 1995 },
  { title: "M", year: 1931 },
  { title: "Requiem for a Dream", year: 2000 },
  { title: "Amélie", year: 2001 },
  { title: "A Clockwork Orange", year: 1971 },
  { title: "Like Stars on Earth", year: 2007 },
  { title: "Taxi Driver", year: 1976 },
  { title: "Lawrence of Arabia", year: 1962 },
  { title: "Double Indemnity", year: 1944 },
  { title: "Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind", year: 2004 },
  { title: "Amadeus", year: 1984 },
  { title: "To Kill a Mockingbird", year: 1962 },
  { title: "Toy Story 3", year: 2010 },
  { title: "Logan", year: 2017 },
  { title: "Full Metal Jacket", year: 1987 },
  { title: "Dangal", year: 2016 },
  { title: "The Sting", year: 1973 },
  { title: "2001: A Space Odyssey", year: 1968 },
  { title: "Singin' in the Rain", year: 1952 },
  { title: "Toy Story", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Bicycle Thieves", year: 1948 },
  { title: "The Kid", year: 1921 },
  { title: "Inglourious Basterds", year: 2009 },
  { title: "Snatch", year: 2000 },
  { title: "3 Idiots", year: 2009 },
  { title: "Monty Python and the Holy Grail", year: 1975 }
];
```

[image: Edit customized Autocomplete]

Related answer:

- [Change border color on Material-UI TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58963242/change-border-color-on-material-ui-textfield/58963947#58963947)

Comment: We have a similar issue for the notchedOutline style within an AutoComplete component. This can be customized via the InputProps param and works but impacts the AutoComplete functionality. We've tried setting this style for input, inputRoot and inputSelect none seem to work. What would be the correct style to override for notchedOutline on an AutoComplete component?

Comment: @GregHouse I've added customizing the outline.

Comment: I wish I could vote more than once on this answer. Thanks a million, @RyanCogswell.

Comment: This answer put me on the right track, but the solution for styling the border is not working for me. I created a sandbox showing where I'm stuck. https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-taussig-ew9de?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @cyrf The solution here is for styling the `outlined` variant. If you are trying to style the underline of the `standard` variant, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778393/how-to-properly-set-colors-on-certain-elements-in-material-ui/57781250#57781250.

Comment: @RyanCogswell excuse me, can I ask you, what do you override in order to change padding and text color? for the text color I tried MuiInputBase-input but without success...thank you

Comment: @July The text color was already being customized in my example (`color: "purple"`). I have just now added customization of `padding-left` to my example.

Comment: @RyanCogswell thank you! I was having problem mostly with the padding :)

Comment: Thanks for this! one question, in the v5 what makes your label blue on focus? I cant seem to see that part.

Comment: @cowley05 The blue label on focus was the [default MUI styling](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.10.11/packages/mui-material/src/FormLabel/FormLabel.js#L47). I've updated my example to show customizing it to purple (via the `&.Mui-focused .MuiInputLabel-outlined` selector).

Answer (score 2):

I figured out it with the doc that says there are two types of "[inputprops](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props)"

so the result code would be

```
<Autocomplete
  id="country-select-demo"
  options={dialCodes}
  underlineStyle={{ display: 'none' }}
  InputProps={{ disableUnderline: uderline }}
  autoHighlight
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.phone}
  renderOption={(option) => (
    <div className="w-100">
      {option.phone}
    </div>
  )}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
      {...params}
      disableUnderline={false}
 
 InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, disableUnderline: true }}
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
 inputProps={{
        ...params.inputProps,
      }}
    />
  )}
/>
```

see in the above code I  have added input props twice.

1. InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, disableUnderline: true }}
2. inputProps={{...params.inputProps, }}

the capital one will do the job and it will remove underline.