# Material-UI Autocomplete is not working when setting TextField InputProps

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [Material-UI Autcomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) component (*Free solo* version) and everything is working fine until I tried to change the color of the text (inside the `TextField`).

My code looks like this:

```
const moreClasses = {
    label: { style: { color: 'blue' } },
    input: {
        style: {
            color: 'red',
            borderBottom: `1px solid green`
        }
    }
};
//...
<Autocomplete
    //... classic props as in the official Doc
    renderInput={params => <TextField 
        {...params} 
        label={'label'} 
        InputLabelProps={moreClasses.label}
        InputProps={moreClasses.input} />
/>
```

**Expected behavior**

When you start typing you can see the autcomplete and the text you type should have a red color.

**Actual behavior**

The text color is red but the autocomplete is not working anymore.

I created [this live running example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-brook-vbhoz?file=/src/App.js) to illustrate the problem with 3 components:

- The Text Field only (works)
- The Autocomplete without changing the color using `InputProps` (works)
- The Autocomplete with changing the color using `InputProps` (does not work)

**Note**

By setting `InputLabelProps` the autocomplete continue working and the color of the label is changed (to blue in the example I shared)! So I can't figure it out why it's not working when setting `InputProps`.

Any feedback about this issue ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Passing `InputProps` causes problems because the `Autocomplete` component [passes InputProps](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.10/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js#L405) as part of the `params` passed to `TextField` so the `InputProps` passed explicitly will completely replace the `InputProps` in `params`.

You can fix this by combining `params.InputProps` with your additional `InputProps` such as in the following code:

```
InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, ...moreClasses.input }}
```

`Autocomplete` also [passes InputLabelProps](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/8baef82396665179c67ca3acfd51e396b947f412/packages/material-ui-lab/src/useAutocomplete/useAutocomplete.js#L912), so even though it doesn't break in as obvious of a manner, you should do the same for `InputLabelProps`:

```
InputLabelProps={{ ...params.InputLabelProps, ...moreClasses.label }}
```

[image: Edit cool-sara-5l79o]

Related answer: [Setting text color, outline, and padding on Material-ui Autocomplete component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984406/setting-text-color-outline-and-padding-on-material-ui-autocomplete-component/58985002#58985002)

Comment: Yes problem solved by combining my extra InputProps with `params.InputProps` as you described. Thank you

Comment: @AlaEddineJEBALI Note my addition about `InputLabelProps` -- you need to do the same for it or some accessibility aspects will be broken.