# Customization of an Input with MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to customize the properties of a basic TextField with filled attribute.

```
<TextField label="Reddit" variant="filled" />
```

Then, I want to edit the:

- backgroundColor
- labelColor
- borderBottomColor
- activeBackgroundColor
- activeLabelColor
- activeBorderBottomColor

For that, I'm using theme.overrides :

```
theme.overrides = {
  ...
    MuiFilledInput: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: filledColor,
        color: baseFontColorDark,
        '& label': {
          color: '#9BA8AE',
        },
}
```

It works for the backgroundColor but not for the label. I tried many other solution in this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/chubbybutton-tmp6y but It didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any attempt to reference the label from within the `MuiFilledInput` override entry will fail because the label is not a descendant element of the input -- it is a sibling (both are descendants of the `FormControl` element when displayed via `TextField`). Instead you can target `MuiInputLabel` directly in the overrides.

Below is an example showing how to control the various colors.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiFilledInput: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: "#ff0",
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: "#ff8"
        },
        "&$focused": {
          backgroundColor: "#dfb"
        }
      },
      underline: {
        "&:before": {
          borderBottomColor: "red"
        },
        "&:hover:not(.Mui-focused):before": {
          borderBottomColor: "green"
        },
        "&:after": {
          // focused
          borderBottomColor: "purple"
        }
      }
    },
    MuiInputLabel: {
      filled: {
        color: "purple",
        "&$focused": {
          color: "green"
        },
        ".MuiFormControl-root:hover &:not($focused)": {
          color: "red"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <TextField label="My Label" defaultValue="My Value" variant="filled" />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit FilledInput colors]

Related answers:

- [How to properly set colors on certain elements in Material-ui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778393/how-to-properly-set-colors-on-certain-elements-in-material-ui/57781250#57781250)
- [How do I custom style the underline of Material-UI without using theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023814/how-do-i-custom-style-the-underline-of-material-ui-without-using-theme/56026253#56026253)